# How to prevent queried posts from being added to cache?

Tags: wp-query, cache

I'm learning about [caching parameters](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Caching_Parameters) and tried this in the `single.php` template:

```
echo count($wp_object_cache->cache['posts']);

$query = new \WP_Query([
  'post_type' => 'post',
  'cache_results' => false,
  'posts_per_page' => 5,
  'ignore_sticky_posts' => true
]);

echo '<br>' . count($wp_object_cache->cache['posts']);
```

The result:

```
3
7
```

Somehow, the `cache_results` parameter didn't work. Am I missing something?

---

I'm using:

- WordPress version 4.6.
- Twentyfifteen theme.
- No plugins/third party services.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The posts array result in `WP_Query` is mapped to `get_post()` ([here](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/cd6d2bae9200f4d2cfc3c0dc974a34f94bf0ad27/wp-includes/query.php#L3673) and [here](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/cd6d2bae9200f4d2cfc3c0dc974a34f94bf0ad27/wp-includes/query.php#L3825)) with:

```
$this->posts = array_map( 'get_post', $this->posts );
```

and that seems to be adding posts to the *object cache* even though the `cache_results` argument is set to `false` in `WP_Query`.

Within the `get_post()` function ([here](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/cd6d2bae9200f4d2cfc3c0dc974a34f94bf0ad27/wp-includes/post.php#L447)) we have:

```
$_post = WP_Post::get_instance( $post );
```

for the case when `$post` is neither a `WP_Post` or an object instance.

The `WP_Post::get_instance` [method](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/cd6d2bae9200f4d2cfc3c0dc974a34f94bf0ad27/wp-includes/class-wp-post.php#L199-L232) contains `wp_cache_get()` and `wp_cache_set()` calls.

So that could explain the behavior you see in your example.

Comment: Ah, thank you! I understand the problem now. But, has WordPress intended to do that or should we submit a ticket to WordPress Trac?

Comment: It sounds like a bug to me, so you should submit a ticket. If it's closed as an expected behavior, then at least we get the explanation for it  ;-) @Dan9

Comment: You meant `wp_cache_add()` or `wp_cache_set()`? Btw, I have never submitted a ticket before but i will give a try. :-)

Comment: The `get_instance()` method [contains both](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/cd6d2bae9200f4d2cfc3c0dc974a34f94bf0ad27/wp-includes/class-wp-post.php#L199-L232) a `wp_cache_get()` and a `wp_cache_set()` call.  It's easy to [create a ticket](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/), but you should first check if a similar ticket has been created before, to avoid it being closed as a duplicate. Good luck and please keep us informed ;-) @Dan9

Comment: Done! Thank you! Hope we can get responses soon! [Here](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/37762) is the link to the ticket.